# Placing absolute position divs in container div

Tags: html, css

I have done a quick HTML page where I have used position:absolute to position all div's relative to the browser edges. When i re-size my browser things always stay on the left side.

What I now want to do is to create a new div and into it place all the other div's. I want this new div to always be centered even if user re-sizes browser with a width of 900px. 
AND all the positioning i have done using absolute should now be with regards to the containing div.

What i have done so far is that i have tried the classic three column tutorials but the problem im having is that the position:absolut dont conform to containing div. Not sure how I will ask the question to make it clearer. Plz ask me questions and I will evolve the question until it makes sense.

Update:
Here is an example of the code I have right now. I want this to be centered in an fixed with div.
http://jsfiddle.net/favetelinguis/nf6mE/

`<body>
    <div class="div4">
        <div class="div5">
            ---------------
        </div>
        <div class="div6">
            -----------------
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="div7">
        Foo<br>
        Hoo<br>
        Moo<br>
    </div>
    <div class="div1">
        A horizontal imagge is placed here
    </div>
    <div class="div2">
        Foo<br>
        Hoo<br>
        Moo<br>
    </div>
    <div class="div3">
        Foo<br>
        Hoo<br>
        Moo<br>
    </div>
</body>`

Comment: can you show a fiddle of the current state of your code ?

Comment: Show some code to help understand the problem.

Comment: The real question is *WHY* you need to position your DIVs in relation to an parent edge. Probably there's other solutions to your problem. Unknown until you show some code.

Comment: Don't forget a DTD at the top of your HTML so the browser can use standards mode... This can often be the cause of some glitches.

Comment: @BigChris what's wrong with simply `<!DOCTYPE html>` ?

Comment: Create a main div and give a `position:relative` to it.

Comment: Nothing wrong with it (especially that one for HTML5), I am just reminding the OP to make sure they've got one on their document :)